# Python PIL-NEAREST "object has no attribute"

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Today I installed PIL but I have few question.

I used this code

```
from PIL import Image


image = Image.open('456.png')
image.rotate(10, image.NEAREST,True).save("img_rotate_30_expand.png")
```

It put out this errors

```
image.rotate(10, image.NEAREST,True).save("img_rotate_30_expand.png")
AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'NEAREST'
```

And

Why this PIL didn't have suggestion.It is really hard for beginner!(below picture)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write `Image.NEAREST` (with a capital 'I').

Comment: wow! It was big mistake!  I thought `image = Image.open('456.png')` so Image can used this comment

Comment: Glad I could help! Cheers.